# Pandas to_csv outputs misaligned data

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

This functions writes a CSV:

```
def onNewData(self, data):  
    zvalues = []
    csv = open("data.csv","w+")
    columnTitleRow = " ValuesofX , ValuesofY , ValuesofZ \n"
    csv.write(columnTitleRow)
    for i in range(data.getNumPoints()):
        zvalues.append(data.getZ(i))
        csv.write((str(data.getX(i))+',')+(str(data.getY(i))+',') + (str(data.getZ(i))+','))   
        csv.write('\n') 
    csv.close()  
    zarray = np.asarray(zvalues)
    p = zarray.reshape (-1, data.width)        
    self.queue.put(p)
```

I use this to read my CSV:

```
# reading data
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np 

  bolts_data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
  print(bolts_data)
```

This is the code that I have written to save the data directly into a CSV file. However when I run a new program to read the CSV file, the data shown is misaligned from the header. This error can be shown in the first picture below. The ideal output that I wish to see is the second picture shown below. Is there any possible solution to fix the misalignment?

Misaligned from the header
[image: Misaligned from the header]

This is the output that I wish to see
[image: This is the output that i wish to see]

Comment: Use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to read and write CSV files.  It will handle all of the necessary encoding/decoding of CSV fields.

Comment: What is the contents of data and how do you read it back?

Comment: @TomKarzes That or `Pandas` if you're into data analysis and stuff.

Comment: i read the contents of the data using the panda function.

Comment: i just added the code on how to read my data in question

Comment: can you share what the first couple of rows of your actual csv file look like?

Comment: I would suggest if dumping data directly to csv is not too important, then make pandas  DataFrame and save it using pandas.to_csv with index=False and then try to read it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Problem in your definition. It generates an extra Column

> Code Modification : You do not need comma after **ValuesofZ**

```
def onNewData(self, data):  
    zvalues = []
    csv = open("data.csv","w+")
    columnTitleRow = " ValuesofX , ValuesofY , ValuesofZ \n"
    csv.write(columnTitleRow)
    for i in range(data.getNumPoints()):
        zvalues.append(data.getZ(i))
        csv.write((str(data.getX(i))+',')+(str(data.getY(i))+',') + (str(data.getZ(i))))    #Here  
        csv.write('\n') 
    csv.close()  
    zarray = np.asarray(zvalues)
    p = zarray.reshape (-1, data.width)        
    self.queue.put(p)
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I think my answer might also work - hopefully OP will let us know!

Comment: @JoshFriedlander there is no such argument in pandas.read_csv as index. you can specify whether to keep index or not while saving using pandas.to_csv() which is never used here. 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Thanks you so much @Hima, your reply helped me alot

Comment: @Sarah If you think the answer posted gave the expected results, you can mark it as answer to your query.

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you use `index_col=False` in your `read_csv` call, it will fix this issue.